# Is ViewBinding by default Thread Safe?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

```
abstract class CoreActivity<VB : ViewBinding> : ScopeActivity(),
    CoroutineScope,
    LifecycleObserver {

    ...
    private lateinit var binding: VB
    ...

    /**
     * Function to access ViewBinding object within Activity.
     * */
    protected fun binding(func: VB.() -> Unit) = launch { binding.run(func) }
}
```

In my current implementation of a BaseActivity for our application, I made **binding** private in order for it to be immutable to its children.

I then made `protected fun binding(func: VB.() -> Unit) = launch { binding.run(func) }`
To allow its children to safely access the contents of the ViewBinding in the Main Thread.

One of my colleagues asked me that he would like to access the views in more of a one-liner. e.g. `binding.textview.text = "Text"`

I then told him that I deliberately made the visibility to the variable private for immutability and thread-safety.

So to the question is ViewBinding by default Thread-Safe?

A sample of generated code of a ViewBinding class:

```
public final class ActivitySplashBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final LinearLayout rootView;

  private ActivitySplashBinding(@NonNull LinearLayout rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public LinearLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivitySplashBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivitySplashBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_splash, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ActivitySplashBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new ActivitySplashBinding((LinearLayout) rootView);
  }
}
```

In the generated class I don't see any indications of Thread Management, but that's just my observation.

Comment: I do not think that's matter in case of `ViewBinding`.  There is no need for it to be thread safe because you can only access UI element from Main Thread if you do it on some other thread you will get exception right away . There is no need for thread safety .

Comment: Also you can make `binding` as protected not private so it can accessible as `binding.textview.text = "Text"` that's the whole idea of extension(creating base components) and changing its visibility has nothing to do with  Thread safety.

Comment: "you can only access UI element from Main Thread if you do it on some other thread you will get exception right away" This is actually the reason why I made the function ```binding {}``` and limited the visibility of ```binding``` to private so that they'll always access the ViewBinding on the main thread.

In the past, there were instances where someone accessed the ViewBinding on a different thread and it was released in Production.